# How do I ignore blank space in a spreadsheet while making a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file that looks like this-

[image]

I want to ignore all blank rows INCLUDING the BSE_IDA.INTV_R (Temporary Table) part and use the column headers beneath that and all the values as the rows in the DataFrame. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that your file is saved with a name `table.xlsx`. Then you can call the `pandas` function to read the spreadsheet with specifying the header flag to indicate at which row your headers are. For example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('table.xlsx', header = 20)
```

Comment: You don't need to change it to a csv file first. Eliminate that part and I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3):

the pandas read_excel function has a skiprows parameter, it helps you to specify the row to skip when reading your file.

From [the doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)s it's said :

> skiprows : list-like
>
> Rows to skip at the beginning (0-indexed)

try

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('/your/path', skiprows = 20 )
```